# PHP Shorthand If Else

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there a way to do the following, but in short if/then syntax:

```
if($method->isAbstract()) {
   $details['abstract'] = true;
}
```

If I do:

```
$details['abstract'] = $method->isAbstract() ? true : null;
```

It is not quite the same, because the array key `abstract` is always set. I only way the array key set if `isAbstract()` is true. To clarify, if isAbstract() is false, don't set the key in the array.

Thanks.

Comment: If `$method->isAbstract()` is false, the array key 'abstract' is going to be defined. I don't want the element to exist in the array if its false.

Comment: Ternary operator **IS NOT** a shorthand to `if-else`. Wondered who said it so that so much people think so?!

Comment: Whats the matter with the first code? Arent 3 lines short enough? You can write it shorter like `if($method->isAbstract()) $details['abstract'] = true;`. More interesting: Why should the key completely missing? Why not `false`? Feels more consistent and it's just a completely obvious `$details['abstract'] = $method->isAbstract()`

Comment: And what's wrong with the first code *that works*?

Comment: What's shorter than a one-line statement?

Comment: @KingCrunch: if he uses `array_keys($details)` somewhere further - then not adding an empty key makes sense

Comment: Only want to see attributes of the method, i.e. if true, don't care about the rest that are false, those aren't attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a PHP interpreter at hand, but I guess this will work:

```
$method->isAbstract() && $details['abstract'] = true;
```

Update: yes, it works → http://codepad.org/lW23FR0j

Comment: Is it a contest of how to write the most difficult-to-understand code?

Comment: Sure it works, but I would discourage this type of usage, it is less clear than the if-else version and difficult to maintain

Comment: @Justin: no, please no! the code should be written for humans, not for interpreter

Comment: @Justin: will you still like it in 6 months time?

Comment: Justin, use gloves man. http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Complicator_0x27_s_Gloves.aspx

Comment: Honestly, here is the full function, you guys think its hard to understand? http://pastie.org/3758103

Comment: The hardest part would be remembering to use `isset()` with the results.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry too much about trying to shorten three lines of code, which in all honesty could be written in one line anyway:

```
if ( $obj->method() ) $data['key'] = 'value' ;
```

However, as [@Mischa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079852/54680) demonstrated, there are shorter ways. You could use the logical operator `&&` to perform assignment as well:

```
$obj->method() && $data['key'] = 'value' ;
```

In this method, the expression on the right is evaluated if the expression on the left is "true".

Another method is the new shorter ternary operator which excludes the second expression. While you presented the long-form ternary as an alternative in your original question, you could also consider the new format provided since PHP 5.3

```
!$obj->method() ?: $data['key'] = 'value' ;
```

Since we're not using the second expression, we invert our test in the first expression. No longer checking for a positive, we are now looking for a negative. When the negative is found, our assignment takes place.

I don't provide this answer to encourage you to avoid 3-line solutions, but only to encourage you to feel free to explore shorter solutions from time to time as they often times lead to parts of the language you  may not have otherwise discovered.